# How to run cProfiler on Scrapy spider

Tags: performance, web-scraping, scrapy, performance-testing

I have a spider in Scrapy and I want to check for bottlenecks. I also have a few classes feeding into the main Spider class. I want to use cProlifer to check for function execution times:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pstats
    import cProfile
    from pstats import SortKey

    cProfile.run("QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider)", "output.dat")

    with open('output_time.txt', 'w') as f:
        p = pstats('output.dat', stream=f)
        p.sort_stats('time').print_stats()

    with open('output_calls.txt', 'w') as f :
        p = pstats('output.dat', stream=f)
        p.sort_stats('calls').print_stats()
```

where `QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider)` is the spider class. Understandably, when running the spider using `scrapy crawl quotes`, I get the following error: `NameError: name 'QuotesSpider' is not defined`.

How do I properly integrate cProfile with Scrapy? And is cProfile the best way to approach this, since Scrapy's requests are async?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit hidden, but you can actually run `cProfile` with a standard `scrapy` command from the command line e.g using your above example for inspiration

```sh
scrapy crawl spider --profile output.dat
```

and then you can just analyse the output as you have done above.

Comment: a bit hidden indeed! many thanks for the help